# Does creation of tensorflow session have overhead?

Tags: tensorflow

I have an image classification model trained with Inception v3 and I have a detection model which runs before this classification model. So now I am creating a session of inception model each time after the detection model runs. Will this affect my run-time, will creating a session each time in tensorflow add overhead??

Algo flow
    |
    |
Detection model (Session)
    |
    |
detection output
    |
    |
image classification on each output

Open to suggessions!!